# IE will not load images

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a div containing 5 images, for some reason only the 3rd and 5th image does not show up in IE. They are png image file types.  When the page loads there is a border for the image and a small icon inside the border with an 'x'.  This is only for the latest IE.  Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.  Day 4 of cross browser headaches.

**HTML**

```
<div id="col3">
    <h4 style="text-align:center;">Affiliations:</h4>
    <br>
    <img src="./Gallery/sponsorimg/astro.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:45px">
    <br>
    <img src="./Gallery/sponsorimg/avngr.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:45px">
    <br>
    <img src="./Gallery/sponsorimg/skulc.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:45px">
    <br>
    <img src="./Gallery/sponsorimg/sqdgrp.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:45px">
    <br>
    <img src="./Gallery/sponsorimg/812.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:45px">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#col3
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 850px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    background:url('dpimg4.jpg');
    border:double 7px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What is this ? " **style="align:center;** "

Comment: Compare the two 'bad' pngs against the rest. make sure they don't have some wonky color depth or whatever that could be triggering an IE bug of some sort.

Comment: Just a sanity check - are you sure images still there? Maybe other browsers just show cache

Comment: If you just the link to the images directly can you open them?

Comment: Can you send us a link to this? It could be a matter of case sensitivity if it is in a Linux environment

Comment: First removed the . in-front of the slash. If that doesn't fix it then try re-saving the images in a different program. I have had IE not recognize images because of the format they were saved in even though it worked in other browsers.

Comment: @Milche..is that relevant ?? Yuriy..I always fail sanity checks..user814064 yes..travis.. nope, its still on my system..Marc I will look into it

Comment: Off-topic suggestion: Rather than line breaks, set those images to display: block and use bottom margins if necessary. Line breaks should rarely be used for layout. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LkzYj/

Comment: Humm. "@Milche..is that relevant ?? **Yuriy..I always fail sanity checks..** user814064 yes..travis.. nope, its still on my system..Marc I will look into it"  This sounds like a major hint: **your physical files**

Comment: If removing/disabling the CSS doesn't make the images appear in IE, then the problem is not CSS related.

Comment: In Internet ex**a small icon inside the border with an 'x'** means 404 'image not found'. Also, an image file with wrong extension will give the same result.

Comment: Hit F12. Go to the Network tab. Look at the downloads.

Comment: So it turns it out the images themselves are the problem, I got different logos from my sponsors and they worked fine in IE.  So I apologize for this not actually being related to CSS.

Comment: So can you 'self answer' your question or remove it, since it's not to be answered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns it out the images themselves are the problem, I got different logos from my sponsors and they worked fine in IE.